# How to filter data from a dataset having dissimilar datatyes in a given Column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset in which one of the attribute(column) is "Age". I want to get all the rows which have the value greater than 20 in the Age column. There are a few rows with NaN as the value of the row column. I tried the following command in pandas

```
df.loc(df['Age'>20])
```

I am getting the error :TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.
I resolved the issue by replacing all the NaN with zeros

```
df.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
```

I want to know if this is appropriate and if there are other methods to filter this dataset.

Comment: Right now you are comparing the string `'Age'` with `20`. You have a lot of typos with your brackets and parentheses. It should probably read: `df.loc[df['Age'] > 20]`. I.e. the comparison is the Series with the value `df['Age'] > 20` and then you use that to slice the DataFrame `df.loc[that_boolean_Series]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a flag and use that flag to handle the logic when it is more complicated.

```
flag = [False if i == np.nan or i <=20 else True for i in df['Age']]
filtered_result = df[flag]
```

I would personally prefer to create a function to deal with more complicated cases:

```
def flag(row):
    result = [False if i == np.nan or i <=20 else True for i in row]
    return result

filtered_result = df[flag(df['Age'])]
```